# Linking Error C++ Libcurl

Tags: c++, c, curl, linker, libraries

I am trying to run the following g++ command

```
gcc client.cc -o client -I$(CURRENTPATH)/curl-7.38.0/include/ -L$(CURRENTPATH)/lib/libcurl.so -lcurl
```

but get this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcurl collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

libcurl.so is located in ./lib I've tried with libcurl.so and lib/libcurl.so.4 and lib/libcurl.so.4.3.0 but always get the same error.

I do not have access to /usr

I've also set my LD_LIBRARY_PATH to include ./lib (full path)

Any ideas?

My understanding is that -L specifies non-traditional paths to libraries, and that LD_LIBRARY_PATH determines where the compiler will look for them.

Comment: Shouldn't you have directory path after `-L`?

Comment: Also could you include in your question why you are using a custom directory and not a system installation of libcurl?

Comment: Plus a note on LD_LIBRARY_PATH, it's for the dynamic linker, i.e. it's being used when you run the executable, not when you build it. Plus I would recommend you to use at least a minimalistic make file setting the `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` and nothing else, allowing you to rune `make client`.

Comment: Use `g++` not `gcc` to compile or link C++ code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-L takes a path rather than a specific library